# Error on minification in console "Refused to execute because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled"

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, mime-types, aem, minify

I need to minify all my js files(using Adobe Experience Manager) in the folder 'js', which also consists of 'angular.min.js'.

While trying to do that, it throws an error in chrome as

> Refused to execute script 'angular.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice you to separate third party libraries like Angular from your own client libraries. Because you usually do not want to minify those third party libraries, but you do want to minify your own client libraries.

Example:

```
etc/
├── clientlibs/
|   └── myproject/
|       └── vendor/
|           └── angular/
|               ├── angular.min.js
|               ├── .content.xml
|               └── js.txt
└── designs/
    └── myproject/
        └── myclientlib/
            ├── js/
            |   └── myclientlib.js
            ├── .content.xml
            └── js.txt
```

Then you could use the following clientlib definitions:

`/etc/clientlibs/myproject/vendor/angular/.content.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
      jcr:primaryType="cq:ClientLibraryFolder"
      categories="[myproject.angular]"
      jsProcessor="[default:none]"/>
```

The `jsProcessor="[default:none]"` disables minification.

`/etc/designs/myproject/myclientlib/.content.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
      jcr:primaryType="cq:ClientLibraryFolder"
      categories="[myproject.myclientlib]"
      jsProcessor="[min:gcc]"/>
```

The `jsProcessor="[min:gcc]"` enables minification by Googles Closure Compiler.

You can easily use both of those clientlibs in your HTL (former Sightly) templates:

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html">
    <sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='myproject.angular'}"/>
    <sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='myproject.myclientlib'}"/>
</sly>
```

Note: You can choose the clientlib category names `myproject.angular` and `myproject.myclientlib` freely. You do not have to use those names in my example. But I would advice using some kind of namespace like `myproject`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked..but ngStorage was also the culprit....I copied ngStorage.js instead of ngStorage.min.js.